# Android Integrated map doesn't work on my Ubuntu

Tags: android

I've been coded for a kind of integrated map Android app on my Windows. , Then, I've been switched to Ubuntu and tried with Eclipse.. Later, when I start my app, I couldn't see my integrated map on both Emulator and my N1.

Any helpful idea is appreciated ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need a new Maps API key, to go with the new debug signing key you have on your Ubuntu/Eclipse setup.